# Create flat excel table from JSON file that includes a hierarchy parent and child objects

Tags: json, excel, powerquery, hierarchy

I have a qualtric derives JSON file which details the parent and child associations of various topics and parent topics in a textiq model.  Below is an exmaple JSON.  I am trying to use Powerquery to import the JSON file and flat the data into an excel table.  In the example there are 3 hierarchies and so I will need to see the labels split into 3 columns.

This is the JSON data

```
{   "version": "2.0",   "operations": [
    {
      "operation": "insert_topic",
      "topic": {
        "topicId": "Topic_4688cc22b4d1b8fc21f1a10b9",
        "label": "H1 Parent Topic A",
        "query": "apples",
        "baseQuery": "apples"
      }
    },
    {
      "operation": "insert_topic",
      "topic": {
        "topicId": "Topic_4da41c224bc519b6d54af4f2",
        "label": "H1 Parent Topic B",
        "query": "oranges",
        "baseQuery": "oranges"
      }
    },
    {
      "operation": "insert_topic",
      "topic": {
        "topicId": "Topic_2c1099b6e6b5a040e210d108797",
        "label": "H2 Topic A1",
        "query": "(apples)&&(blue)",
        "baseQuery": "blue"
      }
    },
    {
      "operation": "insert_topic",
      "topic": {
        "topicId": "Topic_47081b997573137fdfbec914",
        "label": "H2 Topic A2",
        "query": "(apples)&&(red)",
        "baseQuery": "red"
      }
    },
    {
      "operation": "insert_topic",
      "topic": {
        "topicId": "Topic_388937922238a572be5beac3",
        "label": "H2 Topic B1",
        "query": "(oranges)&&(purple)",
        "baseQuery": "purple"
      }
    },
    {
      "operation": "insert_topic",
      "topic": {
        "topicId": "Topic_b92f587891097f85465ed92101",
        "label": "H3 Topic A1"
      }
    },
    {
      "operation": "insert_topic",
      "topic": {
        "topicId": "Topic_d3f27873b48544f7b3434f97",
        "label": "H3 Topic A2"
      }
    },
    {
      "operation": "move_topics",
      "parentLabel": "H1 Parent Topic A",
      "childLabels": [
        "H2 Topic A1",
        "H2 Topic A2"
      ]
    },
    {
      "operation": "move_topics",
      "parentLabel": "H1 Parent Topic B",
      "childLabels": [
        "H2 Topic B1"
      ]
    },
    {
      "operation": "move_topics",
      "parentLabel": "H2 Topic A1",
      "childLabels": [
        "H3 Topic A1",
        "H3 Topic A2"
      ]
    }   ],   "rootNodes": [
    "H1 Parent Topic A",
    "H1 Parent Topic B"   ] }
```

The hierarchy in an excel table needs to look like or be similar to the below table.  Not sure if powerquery will create separatelines for totals of each subtopic / hierarchy but we can handle that when we get to that.

[image: table]

The grey numbers on the side are what I will then create by referencing some response data and will be the number of counts / mentions for each topic.  The whole purpose of creating this is to then put this data into a treemap chart either in excel or powerbi (would be nice to click on areas which then zoom expand).

I've got as far as importing it but I need to know how best to expand the records as half of the records are topics and the other half contains parent / child topic associations.  Once that's done I then need advice on how you tell powerquery what is connected to what.

Thanks

Stage1, import JSON file

[image: Stage1]

Stage2, rootnodes into table (right click on List -> add as a new Query)

[image: Stage2]

Stage 3, repeat stage 2 for operations list -> add as a new Query

Stage 4, convert both queries to table

Stage 5, in the Operations table, click the little expand button top right of header cell.  Click load more and select all the elements

[image: Stage 5]

This is where I probably need some help - I think I need to separate the 'insert_topics' and 'move_topics' elements into separate tables but I don't really know what to do next in order to ensure that 'H1 Parent Topic A' remains tied to 'H2 Topic A1' and 'H3 Topic A1'.

Answer (score 0):

What do you do from here? The path forward is not clear to me

[image]

```
let Source = Json.Document(File.Contents("C:\Temp\a.json")),
Transform = List.Transform (Source[operations], each try _[topic] otherwise _),
#"Converted to Table" = Table.FromList(Transform, Splitter.SplitByNothing(), null, null, ExtraValues.Error) ,
ExpandList= List.Distinct(List.Combine(List.Transform(Table.Column( #"Converted to Table", "Column1"), each if _ is record then Record.FieldNames(_) else {}))),
Expand= Table.ExpandRecordColumn( #"Converted to Table", "Column1", ExpandList,ExpandList),
#"Expanded childLabels" = Table.ExpandListColumn(Expand, "childLabels")
in  #"Expanded childLabels"
```

Comment: Thanks horseyride for that so far....  We can ignore the Query columns.  So that's one extra step.  Hope someone can come along and help with the connecting part. :)

Comment: The path forward is not obvious to me because I can't tell what you are trying to do.  Above is the data in one table. Now what do you want to do with it ?

Comment: I need to get it to the way it's like in the picture of the mock up table I included above.  So the first row it should be H1 Parent Topic A, H2 Topic A1, H3 Topic A1.  The second row should be H1 Parent Topic A, H2 Topic A1, H3 Topic A2.

Comment: Ok, perhaps someone else can help you.